# How IIFE affects this keyword inside it when assigned as object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, reactjs, web

```
var a={
   name:"Rhona",
   check:(function(){
          return this.name;
            })();
   }
 console.log(a.check)// This returns ""
```

An empty string I expected it to return Rhona,it didn't give undefined or null but an empty string whats going on here?

And i also want to know why when I access an objects property which isn't there it gives undefined instead of  giving not defined I recognize undefined is the value given to variables at creation phase,execution phase then initializes the value so if there is no initialization it stays undefined so when i access  an object property lets say a.lastname which isn't present shouldn't java script return not defined  why is it giving undefined instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

The IIFE is executed immediately (that's the first "I"¹). Since you're calling it without doing anything particular to set `this`, `this` defaults to the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode). (See [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work))

You're basically doing this, but without a temporary variable:

```
var temp = (function() {
    return this.name;
})();
var a = {
    name: "Rhona",
    check: temp
}
console.log(a.check) // This returns ""
```

The reason you get `""` rather than `undefined` is that you're using loose mode, and so `this` refers to the global object, which is the window on browsers, and the window has a `name` property (the name of the current window) which is usually empty (`""`).

---

¹ The first "I" in "IIFE" is either "Inline" or "Immediately" depending on who you ask. :-) E.g., "Inline-Invoked Function Expression" or "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression".

Comment: Hmm, I never heard of it being called "inline" but I guess it makes sense. Although, I think "immediately" is more to the point since, as you explain, it is indeed *immediate* when the script is executed, whereas "inline" does not really come across the same way.

Comment: @vlaz: I've always preferred "immediately-" as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to implement what you want:

```
var a={
   name:"Rhona",
   get check(){
          return this.name;
            }
   }
```